# how to solve 'Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null' WARNING issue

Tags: javascript, flutter, android-studio, dart

my application trows a warning saying 'Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null'. The application installs on the mobile phone but does not load the content, shows a blank white screen. Here are the details of the error.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The warning is irrelevant to the actual error. The actual error is below it. Your api returns the wrong result starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of a json response.

As for that warning. It's likely an error due to changes in Flutter 3. Upgrading the `provider` package (where the warning comes from) to its latest version might solve it. The warning itself is quite harmless and shouldn't be breaking anything.